# FFMPEG in Python Returns Corrupted Video

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, type-conversion, mp4

In Python, I run ffmpeg to convert a video to a .mp4 file. However, for some reason, the video it creates is not compatible with anything (I'm pretty sure it's corrupted). The code looks like this:

```
import os

os.system("ffmpeg -i Images/i1.mov Images/edited.mp4 -loglevel quiet")
os.remove("Images/i1.mov")
os.rename("Images/edited.mp4", "Images/i1.mp4")
```

However, the video file created doesn't play.
I am getting an error that just says `killed`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I also tried converting to .WebM rather than .mp4, and it had no effect. (it still gave the same error)

Comment: Is the problem with your Python code or your ffmpeg command or both? Does ffmpeg even execute? What does the log from the ffmpeg process show?

Comment: @llogan yes, it runs. It creates the Images/i1.mp4 file, but I can't open it or play it like I can with other mp4 files.

Comment: Having to make a guess because the ffmpeg log or file info wasn't provided, but try `ffmpeg -i Images/i1.mov -vf format=yuv420p Images/edited.mp4` If you want a real answer, or a more detailed answer, or more suggestions, then show the complete log from the ffmpeg command.